# Styling placeholders in dynamic strings?

Tags: android, string, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In the Now In Android app, there is this code made for highlighting the query when no results are found.

Wrong part highlighted
[image]

Correct highlight
[image]

```
    val message = stringResource(id = searchR.string.search_result_not_found, searchQuery)
    val start = **message.indexOf(searchQuery)**
    Text(
        text = AnnotatedString(
            text = message,
            spanStyles = listOf(
                AnnotatedString.Range(
                    SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold),
                    start = start,
                    end = start + searchQuery.length,
                ),
            ),
        ),
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 24.dp),
    )
```

Is there a better solution to this, which doesn't have the same issue?

Comment: For that specific string resource, use `lastIndexOf()` to find the last matching substring, rather than the first.